# Discord bot multiple servers

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm coding a bot while still learning JS and this questions crossed my mind:

Since JS doesn't handle multithreading.
How does the bot handle multiple events on different guilds/servers? What about its variables? Are values from each event (let's say same event on different guilds) stepping over the previous ones?

Edit: added code in case it's useful

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'nope';

client.on('ready', () => {

  console.log('I am ready!');

});

client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content.substring(0,5) == "nyan!"){ // Si empieza con nyan!

    var mensaje = message.content.substring(5);  // Guardar el contenido en variable auxiliar

    if(mensaje.includes('(')){ // Si tiene parametros

      switch (mensaje.substring(0,mensaje.indexof('(')-1)) {  // Hacer un switch hasta los parametros

        case 'ch':

        console.log(client.guilds);

        var guilds =client.guilds;

        for (var [key, guild] of guilds) {

          console.log(guild);

        }

        guild.createChannel('new-general', 'text');

        break;

      }

    }else{

      switch(mensaje){

        case 'ping':

        message.channel.send(client.ping);

        break;

        case 'destroyMe':

        message.channel.send("I'll be back").then(() => {

          client.destroy();

          process.exit();

        });

        break;

      }

    }

  }

});





client.login(token);
```

Comment: You're asking several different questions here, all of them about code which you say you've written but which you haven't shown us.

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant to the questions as they are kind of generic. My code isn't failing or anything, I just copied and modified code from discordJs examples to make it create channels on certain message

Comment: Delving into the code inside the github repo for discord.js I can see that it uses `websockets` alongside implementing a queue system for events which are passed in. It's likely they use either a series of callbacks or promises when emptying this queue. I could do some more research if your more interested at exactly what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: So It would answer each event one after the other and not simultaneously?
I was just curious so don't worry about it, thanks :D